# Create Tableau Style Parameter in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api

is there a way of creating a tableau style parameter in Power BI? I have a bar chart which shows the total number of raised IT tickets and I'd like a dropdown to be able to switch the legends between showing

i) whether the tickets were resolved on time or not 
ii) the member of staff who raised the ticket
iii) the member of staff who solved the ticket

All the above fields are available from my table, but I'd like the front end user to be able to switch between visualising different legends. It's so easy to do in Tableau but I've made scant progress so far in Power BI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can. Just create a "What if" parameter from the Modeling ribbon.

[image: Modeling Ribbon]

Then you can use that parameter in a measure with some kind of `SWITCH()` functionality to define the behavior for different selections.